# values of new table changing dynamically with the input of the initial table

Tags: excel

I have a question in Excel and need your help!

I can do this if it was static problem but I need my end result to adjust to my input in the table because the year sometimes the year finishes sooner or later or is different or the number of activities vary.

Initial table (It always go in chronological order and it only has 1 or nothing. (I put 0 there because I wanted to put space and didn't know how to do it. also Number of activities may vary)

```
+----------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|      year      | 2016 | 2016 | 2016 | 2017 | 2017 | 2017 |
+----------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| month calendar |   10 |   11 |   12 |    1 |    2 |    3 |
| month project  |    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |    6 |
| Activity 1     |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| Activity 2     |    0 |    0 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |
| Activity 3     |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    1 |    0 |
| Activity 4     |    0 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| Activity 5     |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |
+----------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I want in another sheet

```
+---------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Activity year | 2016       |            |            |            |
|               |            |            |            |            |
| Activity 1    | Activity 2 | Activity 3 | Activity 4 | Activity 5 |
| 25,0%         | 12,5%      | 0,0%       | 25,0%      | 37,5%      |
|               |            |            |            |            |
| Activity year | 2017       |            |            |            |
|               |            |            |            |            |
| Activity 1    | Activity 2 | Activity 3 | Activity 4 | Activity 5 |
| 0,0%          | 37,5%      | 25,0%      | 0,0%       | 37,5%      |
+---------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Now imagine that in the "another sheet" I have nothing and I want the result to adjust to the initial table. How can I do this?

Sorry for bad editing but I can't do better.
Any help is good thank you, I answer any question you might have.

I'm going to add something that is related to this and I also need. I need a formula to get the number of different activities per year that happen at least once for my calculations later. In this case it would be a formula for 2016 which the result is 4 and 2017 is 3.

Comment: Unless you explain how you get `25,0%`, `12,5%`, etc. out of the original table, it would be impossible to help you.

Comment: OK, ok, I got the calculation. You would need to make use of function `SUMIF` with different sets of parameters (e.g. one to get the total number of activities for the year, the other to get the total number of a particular activity). Conditions to be used is for the years at the top row and the activities in the first column. Try to play with those functions and update your post with your attempts and results.

Comment: When I try to divide for all activities in that year I can't get that value. So, I select Sumif sum_range and select all the lines I need, it only looks for values in the first line. I can't sum them all. Example in this case it would sum 2 activities in 2016 instead of 8.

Comment: I manage to solve what I said before by getting a total line for each month. What I can't do automatically now is the year which I have to manually input in the new table but at least I'm a step closer.